# Unity - interface-required public float does not appear in inspector - float value {get; set; }

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I have a float value that I want to edit in the Inspector. The value is required on the class by an interface.

The interface requires that I explicitly state the accessors `{ get; set; }`, but when these are explicitly set, the value does not appear in the Inspector.

`[SerializeField]` does not do the trick.

```
public interface IValueInterface
{
    float value { get; set; }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour, IValueInterface
{
    public float nourishmentValue { get; set; } = 0.1f;
}
```

Comment: `public float value { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also apply the attribute (SerializeField) to the backing field (field created by the auto property) using - field: - before the attribute.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour, IValueInterface
{
   [field: SerializeField]
   public float nourishmentValue { get; set; } = 0.1f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not show properties in inspector. Instead, you can use backing field:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour, IValueInterface
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float NourishmentValue = 0.1f;
    public float nourishmentValue
    {
        get => NourishmentValue;
        set => NourishmentValue = value;
    }
}
```

Other classes would use property `nourishmentValue` but the actual value would be stored in field `NourishmentValue`.

Comment: This answer is also correct, though I went for the one-line approach provided by @Nefisto in this case. Thanks for your contribution.